Does it make sense to have an Access Security page before landing on an Online Statement of Health form?
I'm working on an online statement of health form. The dev asked me to create the first page of the online statement of health form, which would request the user to enter a Security Access Key before getting to the welcome landing page of the Statement of Health Form. The page will have one input field (Access Key) that the user will enter. If the user enters a valid key, it will be redirected to the landing page and will get the message Please enter the valid access key. Does it make sense to create an access key page before the user accesses the welcome page of the online statement of health form?

Why do they need an access key? Where do they get this access key? I don't think anyone can answer whether this makes sense, the only info you've supplied on the access key is that dev asked for it. I generally don't consider "dev asked me to" a valid reason to do anything but I'll look into and evaluate what they're asking for.

The use of an access key is a critical measure for safeguarding the security, privacy, and integrity of online health statements, ensuring that only authorized individuals can access this sensitive information.

Users typically receive the access key through secure and trusted communication channels provided by the organization managing the online health statements. The methods for distributing access keys include:
Email, SMS/Text Message, Postal Mail, Secure Online Portal, Physical Tokens or Smart Cards, & Customer Service.
These methods are designed to ensure that the access key is delivered securely and only to the authorized individual.

Good questions thanks a lot!

Is this a user who is reviewing other people's health data? Or for entering and editing their own statement of health? It definitely sounds like the access key is required. Whether you handle that through an separate page, or a modal might depend on security more that UX. Either way you choose to handle this should probably appear standard to email/pass based auth flows

It's for clients entering and editing their statement of health.
